# Transaction not inserting data into database, keeps rolling back but I can't see the issue

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, transactions, mariadb

The sql commands work in phpmyadmin but won't work in the code. I get no error messages and it appears to be successful but nothing goes inot the database. I have tried various methods but just cannot locate the problem. Really at a loss. Maybe a transaction is not the best way of inserting data into multiple tables?

```
$db->beginTransaction(); // ***********************
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO guests 
VALUES (null, :sFirstName, :sLastName, :sEmail, :sPhone, :sAddressLine1, :sCity, :sCountry);
SELECT * FROM guests
INNER JOIN countries ON guests.country_fk = countries.country_id;');

$stmt->bindValue(':sFirstName', $sFirstName);
$stmt->bindValue(':sLastName', $sLastName);
$stmt->bindValue(':sEmail', $sEmail);
$stmt->bindValue(':sPhone', $sPhone);
$stmt->bindValue(':sAddressLine1', $sAddressLine1);
$stmt->bindValue(':sCity', $sCity);
$stmt->bindValue(':sCountry', $sCountry);
if(  !$stmt->execute() ){ 
  echo 'Cannot update the user '.__LINE__;
  $db->rollBack();
  exit;
}

 $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO reservations VALUES(null, :sRoomId, :sCheckInDate, 
 :sCheckOutDate, :nightsRequested, :iNumberOfGuests);
 SELECT *
 FROM reservations
 INNER JOIN rooms ON reservations.room_fk = rooms.room_id;');
 $stmt->bindValue(':sRoomId', $sRoomId);
$stmt->bindValue(':sCheckInDate', $sCheckInDate);
$stmt->bindValue(':sCheckOutDate', $sCheckOutDate);
$stmt->bindValue(':nightsRequested', $nightsRequested);
$stmt->bindValue(':iNumberOfGuests', $sNumberOfGuests);
if(  !$stmt->execute() ){ 
  echo 'Cannot insert a user '.__LINE__;
  $db->rollBack();
  exit;
}

// SUCCESS
echo 'DONE';
$db->commit(); // ***********************
```

Comment: Why do each of the INSERT statements also include a SELECT statement in the SQL?

Comment: You should start to make it a habit to explicitly mentioning the targeted columns in `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Yes, the issue was the weird SELECT statements. I'm very new to this so thank you for being gentle. I deleted those SELECT statements and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

One statement at a time.  Your two statements happen to be an `INSERT` and a `SELECT`, but any combination of statements will cause trouble.